# Is it possible to make all JMX ports bind strictly to the loopback interface?

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

Using Oracle Java SE 1.8.0_121.

I have established that it's possible to set jmxremote.port and jmxremote.rmi.port to the same value, it's one less port opened. It's also possible to set jmxremote.host=127.0.0.1, to have that port (or those two ports, if you set them differently) bind to the loopback interface only.

However, another port is still dynamically assigned though, and will bind to 0.0.0.0. I was not able to prevent this port with -XX+DisableAttachMechanism, and was also unable to make it bind to anything else than 0.0.0.0.

Is there any method(s) (apart from custom code) in this JVM version to disable this third port, or at least make it bind strictly to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: What port you mean?

Comment: seems to be the third ephemeral random port described in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8035404

Comment: Take a look and see if it helps: https://olegz.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/jmx-connectivity-through-the-firewall/

Comment: Another: https://www.paybackblog.de/java-jmx-how-to-finally-control-your-ports/

Comment: Thanks for the links, I did not find the first one in my initial research. Unfortunately I will not be able to attach custom code to the application I'm trying to monitor, I was trying to achieve this strictly through JVM options. Which I'm coming to the conclusion will not be possible.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the above.